# Spark Union inside a loop gives void

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I try to make a RDD from iterative union from another RDD inside a loop but the result works exclusively if i perform an action on the result RDD inside the loop.

```
var rdd : RDD[Int] = sc.emptyRDD

for ( i <- 1 to 5 ) {
  val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Array(1))
  rdd = rdd ++ rdd1
}
// rdd.foreach(println) => void

for ( i <- 1 to 5 ) {
  val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Array(1))
  rdd = rdd ++ rdd1
  rdd.foreach(x=>x)
}
// rdd.foreach(println) => ( 1,1,1,1,1)
```

If I create `rdd1` outside the loop everything works fine but not inside.

Does it exist a specific lightweight action to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep in mind is that when you apply the `foreach` action to your RDD, the action while apply on each individual worker. Therefore in the first case, if you check the `stdout`'s of each executor, you will find the printed values from `rdd`. If you want these values to be printed to your console, you can aggregate the elements of an RDD (or a subset of them) at the driver, and then apply your function (e.g. `rdd.collect.foreach(println)`, `rdd.take(3).foreach(println)`, etc).